# How to handle session expire in partially loaded divs in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have 2 divs on a page, based on the click id on left i load the content in the right div.
But when session expires, i am expecting the page to redirect to Login, but it does not behave tht way.
some times the button wont work or some times the login screen loads in the right div.
Any suggestions to handle this session expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the IIS simply returns the login-page with an HTTP status code 200 when the session is expired. This makes your ajax not see it as an error.

So you need to do a check in your controller action to see whether the Session has expired, and if it has, you can return an `HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`.

After that, in your ajax, you can use somthing like this:

```
$.ajax({
//...        
error: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if(xhr.status == "401"){ window.location.href = "/login";
    }
}
```